# Magento 2.2 Ajax not working on second time in category page

Tags: ajax, url, pagination, magento2

My site was working fine, suddenly the ajax on category pages is not working on second time. On first time it works fine, whether it is pagination or layered navigation, but on second time it doesn't work. I found out that the URLs are generating incorrect the second time. On first click, it is "headsets?p=2", while after the page ajax loads, it is "headsets&p=2?p=3" and same case is for layered navigation, doesn't work on second time.

Also, the code and database are working on local machine and staging site, I run deployment with git/Jenkins, so code and database are the same on all platforms, and the issue is only on live site.

URL: https://www.thetelecomshop.com/au/headsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was issue in  app/code/Sm/ShopBy/Plugin/Category/View.php  this file.

```
- $requestUri = preg_replace('/(\?|&)ajax=1/', '', $requestUri);
```

so I commented the above line

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! It was some extension issue, that was removing ?ajax=1 from URLs'. Thanks

Comment: How you removed it can you edit the answer with some code ?

Comment: Do you have any idea bout issue please help on the pagination question.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working